# Is it possible to create a custom notification with controls such as buttons in Android? How?

Tags: android

According to the [Android Developers' Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView), it is possible to create a custom notification view.  However, is it possible to create one with controls such as buttons and text views?  If yes, how?

Note that I think it has something to do with [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `RemoteViews` object -- like you would for an app widget -- and put it in the [`contentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentView) public data member of the `Notification`.

Comment: I should have been more clear, how can I receive events from buttons I add to a custom notification view?

Comment: @Gallal: Use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` with your `RemoteViews`, like you would for an app widget. Supply a `PendingIntent` that starts an activity, starts a service, or sends a broadcast, as you see fit.